# Add only specific element to html body depending on javascript condition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning to app creation using Apache Cordova. Depending on the phone screen size I would like to create a div element with specific width/height to display google maps within it. 
Using javascript if/else loop I am set css style preference (width,height etc).
But how can I display only a single div element with style preferences from javascript into HTML>

some code snippets. 
This is to set style for different place holders

```
#mapPlaceholder4S {
    height: 200px; 
    width: 200px;     
    margin-top:20px;     
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#mapPlaceholder5S {
    height: 280px; 
    width: 280px;     
    margin-top:20px;     
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

This is decide which element to use

```
if (screen.availHeight < 481) {
    alert("4S detected");
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapPlaceholder4S"), mapOptions);
} else if (screen.availHeight > 481 &&  screen.availHeight < 569) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapPlaceholder5S"), mapOptions);
}
```

How can I append only one of the placeholders to my html body, depending on what condition gets executed. I am fairly new to HTML and CSS technologies.
I tried using appendChild method from javascript but couldnt get that to work

Comment: Why not use a single `<div>` with an ID or CLASS, then CSS @media queries (which allow you to specify size to change the CSS for the associated ID or CLASS

Comment: If you're trying to display the width relative to the screen size, you could use percentages instead of pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the setAttribute() and removeAttribute() methods in JavaScript. **You will need to put the map within a div. Give the div and id of "googleMap".**

So like:

```
<div id="googleMap"  style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

Then, you can do the following:

So like:

```
.mapPlaceholder4S {
    height: 200px; 
   width: 200px;     
    margin-top:20px;     
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }
.mapPlaceholder5S {
    height: 280px; 
    width: 280px;     
    margin-top:20px;     
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }



if (screen.availHeight < 481) {
     alert("4S detected");
    document.getElementById("googleMap").setAttribute("id", "mapPlaceholder4S");
 } 
 else if (screen.availHeight > 481 &&  screen.availHeight < 569) {
       document.getElementById("googleMap").setAttribute("id", "mapPlaceholder5S");
 }

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapOptions);
```

Comment: `setAttribute` is going to return `undefined`, so you'll be passing `undefined` to `google.maps.Map`. You need to get the element, set the attribute on a separate line, then call `Map` with the element.

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry. First you need to call setAttribute() method on DOM object. Then you can instantiate new google.maps.whatever() object.

Comment: In the interest of further tweaking, why not call `getElementById` just once at the very beginning, then set its attribute based on the condition, then call `new google.maps.Map` once?